# Display <p> on hover of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `div` that has a `p` contained in it. I would like the hide the `p` until the `div` is hovered on. When the div is hovered I would like to change the height of the `div` and display the p at the bottom of the `div`.

Below is what I have, currently it is not responding at all...

**CSS**

```
.tile {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        height: 135px;
        -webkit-transition: height ease 1s;
        -moz-transition: height ease 1s;
        -o-transition: height ease 1s;
        transition: height ease 1s;
    }

   .hideText {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

        .tile:hover {
            height: 260px !important;               
        }

        .hideText:hover {
            -webkit-transition: height ease 1s;
            -moz-transition: height ease 1s;
            -o-transition: height ease 1s;
            transition: height ease 1s;
            visibility: visible;
        }
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="tile blue">
            <a href="#" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">
                <h3 class="title" style="font-size: 30px !important;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Is something broken?</h3>
                <hr />
                <p style="font-size: 19px !important;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Hover to view details</p>
                <p class="hideText">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you'd need two rules. right now the `:hover` stuff is going to be applied to `.hideText` only, meaning that the main `.tile` will be unaffected. so put the div height stuff into a `.tile:hover { ... }` rule, and leave the `.hideText` stuff as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .tile {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        height: 135px;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .hideText {
        height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;

    }

        .title:hover  .hideText{
            height: 260px !important;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   display: block;
        }
    <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="tile blue">
    <a href="#" style="color: black; text-decoration: none;">
    <div class="title" >
     <h3 style="font-size: 30px !important;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Is something broken?</h3>
     <hr />
     <p style="font-size: 19px !important;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Hover to view details</p>
     <p class="hideText">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
     </div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>




change the css tag visible to display, as I shown in the code.
```

Comment: change the text colour to some other colour, or the background colour.

Comment: This is not changing the height of my div... I am wanting the tile (which is the div to just expand...) This is just adding the text below the tile

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/x32ahh7a/

is this the way you need ? Explain clearly what you need @Code

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the height, don't use height but use line-height. The height property edit the height, the line-height align vertically the content. The correct code should be:

```css
.tile {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #000;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        line-height: 70%;
        min-width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: height ease 1s;
        -moz-transition: height ease 1s;
        -o-transition: height ease 1s;
        transition: height ease 1s;
    }

   .hideText {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

        .tile:hover {
            height: 260px !important;               
        }

        .hideText:hover {
            -webkit-transition: height ease 1s;
            -moz-transition: height ease 1s;
            -o-transition: height ease 1s;
            transition: height ease 1s;
            visibility: visible;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="tile blue">
            <a href="#" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">
                <h3 class="title" style="font-size: 30px !important;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Is something broken?</h3>
                <hr />
                <p style="font-size: 19px !important;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Hover to view details</p>
                <p class="hideText">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need it to change the height and display the p text... it is now just changing the height